# How to get dynamic title ,description and image while sharing link from facebook

Tags: laravel-5

I have an issue.

I made a website and it has one module 'news'. When i want click in particular news it contains title,description and image. What i want is when i share link of this particular news in facebook or any social media site i want it retreives title, description and image. And in case when i share other module link it should show logo of website.

Through researched i found meta og tags could solve the problem but i couldnot figure it out.

Helps or hints will be appreciated. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

In Laravel, app.blade.php file, add the below line inside the `<head>` tag.

```
@yield('facebook')
```

And, in news module, you need to include the meta tags as below with news content.

```
@section('facebook')
<meta property="og:title" content="{{ $news->news_title }}"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="{{ $news->image }}"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="{{ $news->description }}"/>
@endsection
```

For other modules, you can simply use

```
@section('facebook')
<meta property="og:image" content="{{ $logo_of_website }}"/>
@endsection
```